# Find and Replace Word

Tags: cewp

Is there any tool or a way to do a find and replace a single word that is inside a Rich Html Field, CEWP in a Publishing enabled Website?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a one-off solution, then the best way would be a small chunk of JavaScript in another CEWP on the page.   See [here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/adding-script-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx) for an example of getting the JavaScript on the page.

If you are looking to do it on a large scale, you need to set it up so the appropriate master pages import a javascript file which contains your relevant script.  More info on that [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722850/how-to-include-javascript-js-file-in-sharepoint-2007).

If you can be a bit more specific about what you are trying to replace, we might be able to provide some basic JavaScript to accomplish it.

Keep in mind that the JavaScript route will only change the page for the end-users viewing the site.  The SharePoint crawler will still index the old values.  This could be a user experience problem depending on what you are trying to replace.  If you instead want to properly update the content in SharePoint, you can always tackle the task with a Powershell script.  You can have a script that will [iterate through all of the CEWP's on a site](https://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2011/09/20/using-powershell-to-update-content-editor-web-parts/).   You can also [replace content on SharePoint content/wiki pages](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sp/archive/2013/05/29/http-www-blogger-com-blogger-g-blogid-8070685728411204795-editor-target-post-postid-1574709978165689298-onpublishedmenu-overviewstats-onclosedmenu-overviewstats-postnum-38-src-postname.aspx).

Comment: We are looking for a permanent change. We need to cover more than 1000 pages

Comment: I edited my answer to address your comment

Comment: We have a  company name on these pages Contoso, This has to be replaced with Wingtip on the entire content pages which are stored in Rich Html Field as well as Content Editor Webparts. Hope i have explained it

Comment: I see.  One issue with doing it in Javascript is that the search crawler will still index and store the old company name.  This could cause much confusion for users seeing search results.  If I were in your position, given something as important as a company name,  I would look to use powershell to attempt to update the content at a large scale level.  I've edited my answer as such.